# opennlp chunker trainer evaluator

Tags: java, opennlp, text-chunking

I've used a training set like the one specified in Opennlp documentation

https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.2-incubating/manual/opennlp.html#tools.chunker.training

to train my Chunker bin file. However, when I use ChunkerEvaluator to crossvalidate, it always gives precision and recall as 0 and fmeasure as -1.0

Can someone please suggest reasons why this may be happening?
I tried many different training sets, with 10 sentences, then 1000, but none of them gave different results.